# MB_CREATE_GOODS_MOVEMENT returns subrc = 5 when running BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

Using me21n to do a returns purchase order (credit) we are getting a pretty uninformative error text in the return table when creating a MIGO entry. This is an enhanced step on the user exit. BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE returns;

> 1, E, WRF_CONS, 010, No data available, , 000000, , , , , GOODSMVT_ITEM, 1, , RPECLNT500

I have attempted to debug further as 'No data available' doesn't mean a whole lot to me. I noticed MB_CREATE_GOODS_MOVEMENT returned a subrc of 5 in the EMKPF structure. Not sure if i have gone off on a tangent here or not... Its pretty darned heavy going in there.

Anyway the create MIGO step is only giving the above return error for a particular vendor code. When we use the exact same data with the exception of Vendor code and Info Record (which populates automatically via the vendor selection) the MIGO step is successful. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is resolved. We had to add partner LF into Site A302 for Vendor profile. Then add the STO details in SPRO. Huzar for config....